# Javascript Function That Does Not Work if the Screen Width is More Than 516px?

Tags: javascript, function, mobile

I've been trying to create a mobile navigation menu with HTML and javascript.
So I created four links, a checkbox and a function that can hide the links when the checkbox is unchecked and unhide them when it is checked, it works fine, the only problem is **I do not want the function to execute if the screen width is more than 516px.**
Here's what I've got so far ("toggle" is the ID of the checkbox and "links" is the ID of the links):

```
function togglemenu() {

  var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

   var links = document.getElementById("links");


  if (toggle.checked == true){
links.style.display = "block";
  }

if (toggle.checked == false){
links.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Here is my updated code:**

```js
function togglemenu() {
  var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
    
  var links = document.getElementById("links");


  if (document.body.clientWidth <= 516) { 
    
    if (toggle.checked == true){
    links.style.display = "block";
  }
       
    if (toggle.checked == false){
    links.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

It still isn't working.
Here is the whole thing in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adam5/2Lgrtbx5/1/)...

Comment: Recommend you look at CSS media queries Adam. Take a look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/evelo2/pen/djpzWR

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). See [Receiving query notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries#Receiving_query_notifications)

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 516px)").matches) {
  /* The viewport is at least 516 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* The viewport is less than 516 pixels wide */
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`use $(window).width()` in `if` statement to get the width of the user window, then check if it is greater than 516px

**JQUERY Code:**

```
function togglemenu() {

var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

var links = document.getElementById("links");


if ($(window).width() > 516) {
    //if width is greater than 516px
    if (toggle.checked == true) {
        links.style.display = "block";
    }

    if (toggle.checked == false) {
        links.style.display = "none";
    }
}

}
```

**JS Code:**

`document.body.clientWidth` use this instead for pure js, you're missing an end bracket `}` in `function togglemenu()`

```
 function togglemenu() {
        alert(document.body.clientWidth);//to check the current client width
        if (document.body.clientWidth <= 516) {
            alert("working");//just to check if it really works
            var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
            var links = document.getElementById("links");
            if (toggle.checked == true) {
                links.style.display = "block";

            }

            if (toggle.checked == false) {
                links.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, welcome :) Please edit your post and add an explanation for your answer. It is required to provide explanation for your answer when you post an answer to a question for better understanding

Comment: When I try this the following error shows up in my console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: Still not working. I added a link to jsfiddle if that helps.

Comment: I edited again, I misunderstood your question before hope I made it right this time. you're missing an end '}' bracket in your toggle function that's why it won't work. use alert() or console.log() to check variables or method is properly called. So you can debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement checks the `document.body.clientWidth` as recommended here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/width

```js
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', test);

function test(event) {
  let target = document.querySelector('#content');
  target.innerHTML = `screen width ${document.body.clientWidth}px`;
  if(document.body.clientWidth <= 516) {
    target.innerHTML = Date.now().toString();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Adam, check your HTML do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in the head section?

Comment: It actually has `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. Is `initial-scale=1.0` a problem?

Comment: No, thats even better. So you might need to place some `console.log()` tests in as the code/principle works. Or, post more code and we can look.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to add a condition in your code.

```
if (window.screen.width > 516 ){
  // do stuff
}
```

Here is [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) for more info.